# Spring redirect to another domain (server) using POST and JSON data

Tags: html, spring, http, spring-mvc, servlets

Hi is possible make redirect to specified url using post method, and put data as json?

For example:

Server a:

```
@GetMapping("redirectToServerB")
public ModelAndView redirectToServerB() {

 ModelAndView  modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirectAutoSubmitForm");
 modelAndView.addObject("redirectUri", uriServerB);

 return modelAndView
}
```

Autosubmit form:

```
<form name="redirectForm" action="" th:action="${redirectUri}" method="post">

<!-- Add hidden params????? -->
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Click here to continue"/>
    </noscript>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.redirectForm.submit();
    };
</script>
```

ServerB

```
@PostMapping("redirectedFromServerA")
public void redirectedFromServerA(@RequestBody SomeObject object) {

   //SomeObject is DTO class - JSON 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is `WebService` concept that you can send `JSONs` and data to another `RestController` or project.
First you must post object to project A `restUrl` and then send it to project B and get result object and get back it to UI. like bellow:

```
@PostMapping("redirectToServerB")
public ModelAndView redirectToServerB(@RequestBody SomeObject object) {
 Result result = new RestTemplate().postForObject("redirectedFromServerA",object,Result.Class);
 ModelAndView  modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
 modelAndView.addObject("result", result );
 return modelAndView
}
```

For more information refer to [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)

Comment: I want to make redirect to another page which is served on serverB and pass in the same request json...

Comment: I confused! do you want just redirect to another URL or  you have `pageA` in `projectA ` and you want send post json to `projectB`?
If you want just redirect you can use forward URL like `return "forward:/redirectedFromServerA";`

Comment: And if you want option two, you should use `webservice` like above.

Comment: I have controller in project1 and controller in project2 , two different servers...